# Question about 4g lte w/ Ubuntu phones

Tags: ubuntu-touch, phone, 4g

Currently, can any Ubuntu phones connect to 4g lte? If not now, is it in the works? If so, what is the ETA? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be Meizu Pro 5 Ubuntu edition

Answer (score 0):

I have the E5 and no way on 4g. It has an issue staying connected to 3g. Yes currently the Pro 5 supports 4g and from what i read works well with it